# .bat Set FontSize - Windows Command Line

Tags: command-line-arguments, command-prompt, cmd, powershell-cmdlet

**Intro:**
I swear have searched around for sometime before posting, but have been unable to find an answer for this..

**Question:**
Regarding Windows Command Line:
is there some way to set the font/text-size via an actual windows command line in a .bat file?

-Not through going to Properties -> etc. *(I understand that quite sufficiently :P)*

--Plz no PowerShell.

**Additional Notes:**
Reason: Thinking of business system based Command Line front-end, PHP back-end.

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using PowerShell, the only way I can think of would be to modify the registry values under `HKCU\Console`.  See the relevant [Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978570.aspx).  However, changes made to the registry values will not update already running console windows.  You won't see your changes until you spawn a new console.

As far as how to make changes to the registry, `reg /help` for more info.